# Cloth - Cloth interactions in Blender

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am trying to run a simulation with cloth cloth simulations. I created two planes,one below the other, joined them along the edge so that it becomes like 'U' folded, then added cloth modifier to this object and pushed it up along z direction. I added a cube with collision modifier. When I simulate, the cloth cloth interactions are not good because of which the cloth pieces cross into each other multiple times. Is there a way in which I can improve the cloth-cloth interactions?

Answer (score 5):

To make the cloth collide with itself in the example you described, enable self collision.
[image: cloth collision]

In the **Physics** context of the **Properties Panel** it is found in the tab **Cloth Collision**.

[image: self collision settings]

Enable **Self Collision** and ajust the other values accordingly.

From the *[Blender Documentation](https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/cloth/settings/collisions.html#self-collisions)*.

> ### Self-collisions
>
> Real cloth cannot permeate itself, so you normally want the cloth to self-collide.
>
> #### Enable Self Collisions
>
> > Click this to tell the cloth object that it should not penetrate
> >     itself. This adds to simulation compute time, but provides more
> >     realistic results. A flag, viewed from a distance does not need this
> >     enabled, but a close-up of a cape or blouse on a character should have
> >     this enabled.
>
> #### Quality
>
> > For higher self-collision quality just increase the Quality and more
> >     self collision layers can be solved. Just keep in mind that you need
> >     to have at least the same Collision Quality value as the Quality
> >     value.
>
> #### Distance
>
> > If you encounter problems, you could also change the Min Distance
> >     value for the self-collisions. The best value is 0.75; for fast things
> >     you better take 1.0. The value 0.5 is quite risky (most likely many
> >     penetrations) but also gives some speedup.

Comment: Hey I tried this out. It's a good solution. Thanks for that. There are a couple of issues though. A distance of 0.8 is quite huge, and it seems like cloth is bouncing off from itself in mid-air. I tried reducing it to 0.6 with higher quality of collision but no luck. Increasing the quality of collision and self collision to 4 also increases the simulation time. Can you think of any other work around?